# How can I manually add memory to the Android emulator?

Tags: google-play-store, android-emulator, ram

I'm planning to buy an Android phone, but I want to try the applications in the Android Market using Android Emulator. I have downloaded many applications and reached the maximum apps I can download because of low memory. My questions is how can I manually add memory to the emulator?

Comment: +1 on Al Everett; and also i'm not sure that Kyle knows that default android emulator can not access market

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a new AVD (Android Virtual Device).

Under Hardware, click New:

From the drop down list of Property, select Device ram size.  Click OK.

You can now put a value beside of Device ram size of how big you want it to be.

Note: You have to create a new AVD.  You can't edit them as far as I know.